# Sharepoint manager property SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, managed-property, crawl

Does anyone know how to index/crawl through people:manager property and display it in either "first name , last name" format as managed property in search?

What I am looking to do is use manager field as a refiner as well as a column in employee search. I am able to index it and use it as such but it is displayed in domain\username format which is not what end user should be seeing.

Comment: Maybe try querying the user profile service again using the managers domain\username and then use the full name property?

Comment: How would i do that? I am very new to SP.
Thank you.

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/af439f0d-d218-44a1-9493-1efd743c57ea/query-sharepoint-user-profile-by-custom-property?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious for more information about the user profile service, you would probably need to do it in JavaScript so lookup how to include JavaScript in SP pages too.